# ReactQuery mutation loops component

Tags: react-query

I have a post hook from orval called usePostPrice that gets some prices in a array of products.

I use it like this:

```
const { mutate: pricesMutator, isLoading: isFetchingPrices } = usePostPrice();
```

I then have a map in my return that calls i function that get prices using the hook.

```
const findPriceProduct = useCallback(
  (product: IDonorProduct) => {

    if (pricesMutator && priceProducts.length > 0 && !loadingSession && !isFetchingPrices) {
      pricesMutator(
        {
          data: {
            products: priceProducts,
          },
        },
        {
          onSettled: (data) => {
            if (data?.ok) {
              console.log("data: ", data);
              data?.products?.find((p) => p.productGuid === product.itemGuid);
            }
          },
        }
      );
    }

  },
  [pricesMutator, priceProducts, !loadingSession, !isFetchingPrices]
);
```

It just loops my component and i dont se the console.log inside onSettled.

Update:
Found out that i get the data in OnSuccess but it enver enters onSettled.

Comment: your code doesn't cover the case where `onSettled` is call with data being `undefined` or includes an error. did you check this?